# How to count records by each month from two related tables using Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two related tables, parent table has `datetime` and rest of the data is in the child table. Thank you for helping.

Using the following linq, the code works fine for single table:

```
var query = (from m in Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
             join c in Machines on m equals c.Date.Month into monthGroup
             select new { Month = m, Count = monthGroup.Count() }).ToList();

foreach (var data in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Month " + data.Month + "  Count " + data.Count);
}
```

It returns counts of each month and zero count if no records were inserted in that month. I want to count based on the unique **address** that is in the child table. An **Address** can have many occurrences in each month but I want only unique each month.

Table structure is :

**Machines:**

```
MachineId, MachineName, Date
```

**Addresses :**

```
AddressId, address, MachineId
```

Comment: What makes an `Address` unique?

Comment: it is not unique itself, i mean distinct ones from each month. So if there 100 addresses in a month, and I dont want count of duplicate ones.

Comment: Well, let me rephrase my question. What makes an address a duplicate?

Comment: in a day if an address has multiple occurrences, I just want one , so if address C1:G1:22:2T:8Y appears more than once in a day in the table, makes it duplicate.